# play framework with spray json

Tags: playframework, spray-json

can I use spray-json for json serialization in play framework? 
I have tried it out but it does seems not to work.

I tried a simple action

```
  def getColor(sn: Int ) = Action {
           import MyJsonProtocol._
            val c = Color("color",33,23,99)
           Ok(c.toJson) 
          }
```

I get the following error

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[Cannot write an instance of spray.json.JsValue to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[spray.json.JsValue]]
```

Answer (score 1):

funny ;)  i fixed it myself by calling the prettyPrint method on the toJson

```
Ok(c.toJson.prettyPrint)
```